# word boundary \b doesn't work on string with dot in Python regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

I need to replace a particular word `abc` with `abc_test`, but with `\b`, `.` is considered as word boundary so I get unexpected result. Can someone help me figure out how can I skip replacement for `.` with `/b`?

This is my script:

```
import re
f = open("4.txt", "r").read()
op = re.sub(r'\babc\b', 'abc_test', f)
print(op)
```

This is my input file 4.txt:

```
abc
abc xyz
abc
abc.asd
```

Output:

```
abc_test
abc_test xyz
abc_ztx
abc_test.asd # This gets replaced which is not as expected
```

Expected output:

```
abc_test
abc_test xyz
abc_ztx
abc.asd # This shouldn't be replaced
```

How can I restrict the regex to skip `abc.asd` here?

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary and there is a word boundary between `abc` and `.`. The question is, **why** is it not expected? If you just want to avoid matching before a `.`, use `r'\babc\b(?!\.)'`

Comment: Yes, that is what I was missing, thank you for pointing it out! If you can post this as an answer, I will accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: It appears I have already answered a question explaining this trick.